# How to run a PySpark job with Airflow in a dockerized environment

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose, airflow

I followed the official  [Airflow docker guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html).
It works fine for most of the simple jobs I have.

I tried to use [this guide](https://medium.com/codex/executing-spark-jobs-with-apache-airflow-3596717bbbe3) for that I needed to add in the .env file this line:

```
_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS=pyspark xlrd apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark
```

Unfortunately, the dag is not being loaded.

The problem seems to be related to JAVA_HOME because the docker output shows this message:

```
airflow-scheduler_1  | is not set
```

In the Airflow web GUI it shows the following erro:
[image]

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/SparkETL.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 339, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 108, in launch_gateway
    raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

I tried to add `install -y openjdk-11-jdk` command in the docker-compose, and set `JAVA_HOME: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64'` also in the docker compose. In this situation airflow_schedule dumps that the path does not exist.